# jQuery Mobile - how to get search icon on the search bar?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement a search bar 

But i was **not** able to display the search icon on the search bar. 
Here is the [code (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/cWUfu/).
I found the default style overrides my custom style.

HTML

```
<div id="search_controls">
    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="e.g. restaurant name, cuisine" />
</div>

input.ui-input-text, textarea.ui-input-text {
background-image: none;
padding: .4em;
margin: .5em 0;
line-height: 1.4;
font-size: 16px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
outline: 0;
}
```

CUSTOM STYLE

```
#search_controls + input.ui-input-text{
    background: url('../img/search_icon.png') 98% center no-repeat!important;
    height: 26px;
    padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 99%!important;
    outline: 0;
}
```

How to address this issue?

Comment: Hi, Rephrase your question to get a response...

Comment: i found below default style overrides my style DEFAULT STYLE input.ui-input-text, textarea.ui-input-text {
background-image: none;
padding: .4em;
margin: .5em 0;
line-height: 1.4;
font-size: 16px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
outline: 0;
}

Comment: I edited your question and digged out the image and your code...;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably I know now what you mean...
just remove the `+` sign in your custom CSS and it works ;-)...

[image]

example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  #search_controls input.ui-input-text{
    background: url('taifun.png') 98% center no-repeat!important;
    height: 26px;
    padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 99%!important;
    outline: 0;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div id="search_controls">
      <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="e.g. restaurant name, cuisine" />
    </div>
  </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<input type="text" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a" name="" id="searchinput1" placeholder=" Search..." value="" data-type="search">
```